# Left shift doesn't work in KSP or other Unity games

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've got an issue in several different unity games: the LeftShift key doesn't recognize, nor does RightShift. Every other key works fine, and LeftShift works in other games and outside of Kerbal.

I'm running Windows 8.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried going through the settings and explicitly setting throttle up et al to the left shift key?  Also, I'm thinking this may be an issue related to using a localized keyboard layout instead of Win8 specifically.

Comment: I did. It's fixed, was actually Synergy hijacking the keyboard in a few of the games.

Comment: @TravisOlbrich Can you post that as an answer so that this issue can be marked as solved? Self-answering once you've discovered the answer is totally ok here!

Comment: It seems odd that it would hijack the shift key, but nothing else.  At least you found out what was wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Synergy was hijacking the shift key. Quitting Synergy solved the issue.

Comment: Oh god I love you so much right now

Comment: Synergy also didn't show any indication that it was running, other than a process in the Task Manager, making this really hard to solve.